# Get return when submiting form using jquery (without refresh)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a code to call a PHP page when a form is submited on my page (below):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ajaxPVT').on('submit',function(e) {        
        $.ajax({
            url:'action.php',
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                alert('success!!');
            },
            error:function(data){
                alert('error');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

It works fine. It calls the action.php and show an alert like SUCESS!!.

My problem is: I would like to get a return from php file..

For example.. if something there isnt OK, then return false...

And avoid form submiting showing and error alert.

Thanks a lot, guys.

Comment: The `data` parameter of the `success` callback is the response from your PHP, so you can check for errors.

Comment: with ajax you cannot do like this as this is asynchronous call.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Who told you that??

Comment: @BlankHead, I am not aware if there is a way to submit form and inside submit form call ajax and you can wait till ajax returns successfull/ not. Will you please explain me how to do this. I am new to ajax and form submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your php file, use something like this and you will go through the `error` function instead. I believe all 4xx and 5xx codes will work.

```
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not found');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case it wpuld probably be best to let de Php return a JSON string containing either a success or a errorcode, accomanied by a message.

Then in your success method you will analyse the data variable. Based on the successcode in the returned object you will either show a thanks-message or an error in the form.

Answer (score 0):

- Your logic must be written in php file
- As you submit your form your data goes to action.php file
- there you can just echo json data
- or simple "success"
- Do this in your ajax

> ```
> success:function(data){ 
>        if(data == "success")
>          alert("success");
>        else
>          alert("Fail");
>      }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

With Ajax it is not possible to `return false` to form and show error as submit form and ajax call are asynchronus.

Instead, you can call ajax on button click and submit form if ajax is successfull.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ajaxButton').on('click',function(e) {

      $.ajax({
       url:'action.php',
       data:$(this).serialize(),
       type:'POST',
       success:function(data){
           console.log(data);
           alert('success!!');
          //submit your form here
          $('#formId').submit();
           },
           error:function(data){
           alert('error');
          }
       });
     e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```